# I want to increase my gear range, will my front gears affect the cassette I can use?

Tags: road-bike

I'm contemplating increasing my road bikes gear range. I have a race coming up that has some significant climbing. My question is if I want to increase the teeth on my rear cassette will that be limited by the type of gears I have at the front? My set up currently is a Shimano Claris FD 2403 front mech, Shimano HG50-8 11-30t cassette. Would I be able to increase the cassette to 32t or more without it being incompatible with the front mech?

Comment: Stay with an 8 speed cassette - anything else will require a new brifter/shifter.

Comment: If you can't get a bigger big cog on the back, the other option is to fit a smaller inner gear on your front chainring.  Again, this is limited by various things, including cost!

Comment: What model rear derailleur does your bicycle have?  With that information, it's possible to calculate whether or not you can safely use a 32t or more cassette.

Comment: I run a bontrager triple crank, the large chainwheel having 53 teeth. My rear drive is Shimano Claris, SGS cage. Cassette is a SRAAM 8 speed 11-32. This set up works great. My B-adjust bolt is one or two threads shy of fully in/tight. I don't ever run the large-large combo, but the derailleur makes the shift smoothly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Front derailleurs don't care what size cassette you have. However, the front rings do affect the size of cassette you can run, because rear derailleurs have a *total capacity* specification. Total capacity is a measure of how much chain slack the derailleur can take up. The capacity required is: (difference in cassette large/small sprocket tooth counts) + (difference in chainring large/small sprocket tooth counts). Note the *difference* is what counts, not the actual sizes.

If you have a FD-2403 front derailleur you must have a triple setup, so presumably you have the [RD-2400-GS](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-2400/RD-2400-GS.html) (long cage) rear derailleur and 50/39/30 crank. The derailleur has a max sprocket size of 32 and total capacity of 41 so a 11-32 cassette will work fine ((32-11)+(50-30)=41).

People have expressed opinions on this site that running a cassette with a large sprocket 2 teeth larger than what Shimano states works OK, but you can't violate total capacity. Doing so risks shifting into large chainring-large sprocket and snapping your chain and/or ripping your derailleur off.

If you do fit an 11-32 cassette you may need a longer chain length. You will want to run a new chain with the new cassette anyway.

---

Update: If you *really* want to run a bigger cassette you could put an 8 or 9 speed MTB derailleur on. Shimano used the same derailleur actuation ratio for road and MTB 7, 8 an 9 groupsets (and road 10). Just as an example, an Acera M360 8 speed derailleur (from 2008, but still available) has a total cap of 43 and max sprocket of 34. (Specs can be found in [this](http://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2009_LINE-UP_CHART.pdf)).

Comment: *ripping your derailleur off* Which then finds its way into the spokes of your rear wheel, destroying that too.

Comment: Oh man great answer thank you so much! If I want to go up to a 34t would just changing the derailer fix that issue?

Comment: @AJS see update to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your cassette won't affect your front mech. You may need a longer chain, and your rear derailleur might not be designed to handle the larger cassette, but that's another question.

Also, the difference between a 30-tooth and 32-tooth gear is barely noticeable. Go for a 34-tooth low gear.

Comment: Is the asker likely to have derailleur compatibility issues with a 34-tooth cassette?

Comment: According to Shimano a 34 tooth cassette requires a medium-cage RD, a short-cage RD handles a 32 cassette.